# How to add npm-check-update as a custom script in package.json?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Basically have this:

```
"scripts": {
    "checkUpdate": "npm-check-updates",
    "updateConfig": "ncu-u"
},
```

but when I run `npm checkUpdate` I get:

> where  is one of:
> access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit,
> clean-install, clean-install-test, completion, config,
> create, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor,
> edit, explore, fund, get, help, help-search, hook, i, init,
> install, install-ci-test, install-test, it, link, list, ln,
> login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix,
> profile, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root,
> run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,
> stars, start, stop, t, team, test, token, tst, un,
> uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view,
> whoami
>
> npm  -h  quick help on  npm -l            display
> full usage info npm help    search for help on  npm help
> npm      involved overview

Comment: You have done. If you mean how do you _run_ it, `npm run checkUpdate`?

Comment: This will be a good laugh in the future. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm run checkUpdate` should make it work

Comment: Out of curiosity. Why do I in some cases need to type "run" and in others just the script name?

Comment: @CodingLittle I was also thinking some time to find out what is wrong here haha even if we use those scripts so many times

Comment: Please view the new comment